# How do I include a timezone in my d3 time formatted data?

Tags: date, d3.js, time, formatting, axis

I"m using d3 v4.  My x-axis data consists of time in milliseconds (since 1970).  I would like to display this as eastern standard time, for example

```
08/09/17 5:20 PM EDT
```

so I tried

```
focus.select("text").text(d.value).append("tspan")
      .attr("x", 10).attr("dy", "1.5em").text(d3.timeFormat("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p %Z+5")(d.index_date));
```

but unfortunately it is instead displaying as

```
08/09/17 5:20 PM -0500 +%
```

What's the proper way to format the date/time as EDT (US Eastern standard time)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3 v4 [time format](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md#time-formats-d3-time-format) has support for custom locales, but I don't see anything for time zones (so you can show the date-time in Russian, but only with the browser's local time zone), which is understandable, as it requires having the TZ data locally.

The only way I see is to bring another library.
**Edit:** no wait, [`Date.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) supports `timeZone` parameter (but it seems browser support is limited, e.g. Android does not support this <sub>(well, Chrome does, Firefox does not, and maybe WebViews won't)</sub>):

```
new Date(1502769000000).toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'America/New_York' })
// 8/14/2017, 11:50:00 PM"
```

(so you'd just need to add the "EDT" suffix yourself)

Alternatively, with [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) (which itself requires [moment](https://momentjs.com/)):

```
var t = 1502769000000;
var f = 'M/D/Y h:mma z';
moment(t).tz('America/New_York').format(f);
// 8/14/2017 11:50pm EDT
moment(t).tz('Europe/Paris').format(f);
// 8/15/2017 5:50am CEST
```

Since you always need the same TZ, you might be interested to note that it's also technically possible to [build a lighter version yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43561570/6730571) with only the subset of TZ data you require.

Comment: Other than including the library you linked to here is there anything else I need to do to get moment working?   After including the library and running your code I'm getting the error, "ReferenceError: moment is not defined"

Comment: Ah, the library I linked to is a plugin for [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/), so you need to install 2 libraries, sorry that was unclear

Comment: K, I included the "moment" JS file you linked to above in the line before th emoment-timezone file but yet I still get the error, "TypeError: moment is undefined" coming from http://localhost:3000/assets/moment-timezone.self-3635c5815990517b36f417fa9112870283008691bbd03d999215a2bce80e42fb.js?body=1 upon page load.

Comment: Hmm see [example](https://zami.fr/7c3ed4f7c7fb3529e783527bad9d0296.html) -- (also please notice my edit, maybe there is a no-library solution)

Comment: Yeah taht no-library solution is lookin' solid.

Comment: Yeah well, add Safari 9 to the list of browsers that don't support it. Depending on your site audience, you might want to consider moment-timezone.

Answer (score 0):

The toString() method on a regular javascript Date object includes the time zone abbreviation but the d3-time-format library doesn't seem to include a way to get it.

```
var date = new Date(123456789);
console.log(date.toString()); //"Fri Jan 02 1970 05:17:36 GMT-0500 (EST)"

var d3Format = d3.timeFormat("%c %Z");
console.log(d3Format(date)); //"1/2/1970, 5:17:36 AM -0500"
```

So you'll have to add in the time zone abbreviation manually with your own function.

```
var jenny = new Date(8675309);
var d3Format = d3.timeFormat("%c"); //%c is shorthand for %x %X (date and time)

// Add "EST" to the end of every string
var addEST = function(date) {
    return d3Format(date) + " EST";
}

console.log(addEST(jenny)); //"12/31/1969, 9:24:35 PM EST"
```

Comment: You mean "var d3Format = d3.timeFormat("%c %Z");" instead of what you have, right?  B/c I was getting a JS error complaining about undefined timeformat the other way.  Anyway, even with what I suggest here, the output is still incorrect.  I'm getting "8/9/2017, 1:10:08 AM -0500 CDT" but what I want is "8/29/2017 2:10:08 AM EDT".

Comment: Sure, what you call your function depends on whatever name you choose to give the imported d3 library. d3.timeFormat("%c") will give you back just the date and time with no time zone information.

Comment: Another thing I didn't consider is date.toString() will return your current time zone, so if you're somewhere in central time it will always return CDT. If you want your data to all be EST then forget the whole regex business and just concatenate "EST" to the d3 formatted string.

Comment: I need an example here b/c if I concatenate "EST" to the string, taht would give me "8/9/2017, 1:10:08 AM -0500 CDT EST" which is all kinds of confusing.

Comment: Ok, I'll update my above code snipped to reflect what I mean

Comment: Thx although its still nto quite right.  Its showing things like "8/10/2017, 2:40:09 PM EST" but it should be "8/10/2017, 3:40:09 PM EST".  I think the "new Date(8675309);" is returning things in CDT b/c taht's where I am, but this function should display the time in EST whether you're on a browser in Denver, Anchorage, or Mars.

Comment: Ok I see the problem now I think. The d3.timeFormat function only works on Date objects, and if you pass in a number or string instead it will convert to a Date. So it's always biased to your location. The only alternative I see is d3.utcFormat, which interprets dates without time zones, then converting to EST manually. But then you have to account for daylight savings time which is a mess... Sorry I don't seem to be of much help

Comment: Np I appreciate your thoughts on all this.  It may lead to an answer yet.